# Вывести 5 самых популярных ингрдиентов, где 2 из них будут алкогольными

Tags: sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте! Скажите, можно ли как-то вывести из БД вывести 5 самых популярных ингредиентов, где 2 из них будут алкогольными. У меня получилось вывести 5 самых попурных алкогольных ингредиентов :

```
SELECT `component_id`,`component_name` count(`component_id`) FROM cocktail WHERE (`component_typeName`='alkohol' OR `component_typeName`='likier') GROUP BY `component_id` ORDER BY count(`component_id`) desc LIMIT 0,5
```

Сама БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Суть в том, что у меня есть коктейль в нем ингрдиенты, и получается если у меня 5 ингрдиентов в коктейле у меня 5 записей, в которых будет отличаться id и информация о компоненте, если 2 ингредиента - 2 записи. Надеюсь, понятно все объяснил. 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не особо изящно нужно, то, наверное, подойдет и такой способ:

```
(SELECT `component_id`,`component_name`, count(`component_id`) FROM cocktail WHERE (`component_typeName`='alkohol' OR `component_typeName`='likier') GROUP BY `component_id` ORDER BY count(`component_id`) DESC LIMIT 2)
union all
(SELECT `component_id`,`component_name`, count(`component_id`) FROM cocktail WHERE (`component_typeName`<>'alkohol' AND `component_typeName`<>'likier') GROUP BY `component_id` ORDER BY count(`component_id`) DESC LIMIT 3)
```

Comment: Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: 1) Подзапросы обрамить скобками 2) Если выпивки менее 2 записей, получим неверный результат

Comment: @Akina я так понимаю, что там немаленькая табличка, но я ж сразу написал, что решение в лоб, не изящное))

Comment: @PavelNewSky Изящность - это для школьников и студентов. А с точки зрения эффективности к запросу претензий нет.